Conditional workflow ordering on GitHub
Suppose I have two GitHub Actions workflow files: ci.yml and docker_build.yml.
First one uses the Docker image from Docker Hub. Second one builds and pushes this image to Docker Hub.
docker_build.yml workflow only runs when Dockerfile (and workflow file) is changed:
name: Build and push docker image
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - .github/workflows/docker_build.yml #maybe later i will update it 
      - Dockerfile
...

ci.yml workflow runs only when codebase is changed:
name: Build and Test

on:
  push:
    paths:
      - .github/workflows/ci.yml
      - src/**
      - include/**
      - test/**
      - CMakeLists.txt
...

The Dockerfile updates are not as frequent as code updates.
I expect those scenarios to be valid:

Code changed -> only Build and Test workflow is run

Dockerfile changed -> only Build and push docker image workflow is run

Dockerfile and code changed -> Build and push docker image workflow is run followed by  Build and Test workflow.


I tried to add those lines in ci.yml:
name: Build and Test

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: [ "Build and push docker image" ]
    types:
      - completed
  push:
    paths:
      - .github/workflows/ci.yml
      - src/**
      - include/**
      - test/**
      - CMakeLists.txt

The first two scenarios run as expected. But the third scenario run Build and Test workflow without waiting for docker workflow to be completed. How can this be resolved?

Just add logic to the end of 'Build and Test' workflow - "if Dockerfile also changed, now trigger 'Build and push docker image' workflow" (or vice versa, but why would you push the image before testing the code?!)

This image(enviroment) is used to build and run the code from repository. If the build image changes( p.i. at some point i have added new library) i would like to create new image. So that's why. Maybe later i will create release(that contains my application) image, but in that case i will trim unnesesary things (since envoroment image is to bulky).

@jonrsharpe , Also how would i check that Dockerfile was checked 'to trigger workflow if: contains(github.event.head_commit.modified, 'Dockerfile') doesn't seem to work(for jobs).
